# getRange and setValues functions returning a mismatch between data and number of columns

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to populate column A1 in the swimmerSheet with the names of the users (C column) in my userSheet matching the "Nageur" status (D column).

As I'm a newbie to Google Script, I don't know how to adapt this code below. Every solution I find doing my researches are returning an error message.

For now, the code below is setting the whole row of data I get in the userSheet to the first row of my swimmerSheet. I only want to get the full name (C column of userSheet) and put it in the first column of swimmerSheet.

```
function transferSwimmerInApp() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var userSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Utilisateurs');
  var swimmerSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Nageurs')
  
  // Get range with data from original sheet:
  var firstRow = 1;
  var firstCol = 3;
  var numRows = userSheet.getLastRow();
  var numCols = 3;
  var data_range = userSheet.getRange(firstRow, firstCol, numRows, numCols).getValues();

  //This is the status of the swimmer
  var status = 'Nageur';
  var check = userSheet.getRange('D2:D').getValues(); //The range to if statement against

  // Iterates through all rows of data from "Utilisateurs"
  for (var i=0;i<check.length; i++) {
    var col = data_range[i]; // Current row
    
    if(check[i] == status) { 
      swimmerSheet.getRange(2, 1, 1, 1).setValues([col]) 
   }
  }
}
```

Does anyone know how I could adapt it so it executes perfectly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Recommendation**

You can actually use the [QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343) function to be able to populate column A1 in the 'Nageurs' with the names of the users (C column) in your 'Utilisateurs' sheet matching the "Nageur" status.

```
=QUERY(Utilisateurs!A:D,"SELECT C WHERE D = 'Nageur'")
```

The query function on the 'Nageurs' sheet:

[image]

Here's the 'Utilisateurs' sheet:

[image]

Comment: Why making it simple while you can make it complicated haha ! Thanks a lot, didn't thought about it, was caught in this script view for too long.

Comment: You're very welcome. You may want to also check all Google Sheets' predefined functions here https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273 on how to manipulate sheets data without using Apps Script just yet.